# Getting 407 Proxy Authentication Required for js, images, aspx and html requests in firebug console

Tags: java, asp.net, iis, applet

I have a web site which uses the Java applet for file upload. Applet has JavaScript methods exposed which i am trying to use.

Some days back it was working fine for me but now i am getting to see following error in the firebug console while accessing the web site for all the html, JS, image file requests and the work-flow is not working now.

```
"NetworkError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. ) - http://test.server.com/javascript/dates.js"
```

Does anybody faced something like this ? any inputs would be helpful.
The web site is behind IIS6.0 on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple request to authenticate the client against your ISA proxy. Make your client Kerberos-aware for the proxy and everything should work again.